# Package "libg2o" does not follow the version conventions

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/hydro
-- This workspace overlays: /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/hydro
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
HI,
when i did catkin_make i had this warning:

-- Python version: 2.7
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.90
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on

WARNING: Package "libg2o" does not follow the version conventions. It should not contain leading zeros (unless the number is 0).

I didn't understand where is the problem!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206067/package-%22libg2o%22-does-not-follow-the-version-conventions/) by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2015-03-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's just a warning that the package does not follow the specified version patterns. It does not diverge far enough to break any tools in this case so you do not need to worry about it.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1